# MySQL REGEXP digit exact match not working

Tags: mysql, regex

I have this query:

```
SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE foo REGEXP '[[:digit:]]{10}';
```

Which is returning `bar` rows where `foo` is longer in number of characters than 10.

Same happens if I try with `[0-9]{10}`. It's like it's not taking into account the `{10}` to match exactly those rows where foo contains only 10 digits.

The expected regular expression should be matching values like:

```
1231231231
```

Only digits, 10 characters, but isn't.

`foo` is a string column. I'm using mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.26, for Linux (x86_64).

Comment: Use anchors: `^[[:digit:]]{10}$`

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place anchors around your regex pattern.  Also, I prefer using `[0-9]` to represent any digit, because it is more portable to other regex flavors.

```
SELECT foo
FROM bar
WHERE foo REGEXP '^[0-9]{10}$';
```

Note that I also placed `^` and `$` anchors around the pattern, to ensure that the entire `foo` column must be ten digits.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks! I've tried `[0-9]{10}` with no results before. Now the same for `'^[0-9]{10}$'` no results whatsoever.

Comment: @sab My logic is [working in this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=09827137b5416b2795016b868ec877d3).  Maybe your data has a problem.  Could there be extra whitespace before or after all the numbers?

Comment: Ah sorry, I had a condition somewhere else. `^[0-9]{10}$` is working pretty well. Thanks! Will accept in a moment ;)